# "Make" Error while Apache upgrade from 2.0.63 to 2.0.65 with openssl-0.9.7e

Tags: apache

Compiled apache in i86pc:

Before compiling apache compiled openssl0.9.7e. 
Then configured with preferred options:

./configure --prefix=/usr/apache2 --enable-mods-shared="all ssl auth_gss cache  deflate disk_cache file_cache mem_cache perl proxy_connect proxy proxy_ftp proxy_http suexec" --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl 
    "make"
Error:

```
__ctype                             0x637       /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(v3_conf.o)
__ctype                             0x6b7       /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(v3_conf.o)
ld: fatal: relocations remain against allocatable but non-writable sections
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `mod_ssl.la'
Current working directory /vikram/apache_2_0_65/httpd-2.0.65/modules/ssl
*** Error code 1
The following command caused the error:
if test `pwd` = "/vikram/apache_2_0_65/httpd-2.0.65"; then \
    echo "" ; \
fi; \
list=''; for i in $list; do \
    target="shared-build"; \
    if test "$i" = "."; then \
        made_local=yes; \
        target="local-shared-build"; \
    fi; \
    if test "$i" != "srclib"; then \
        (cd $i && make $target) || exit 1; \
    fi; \
done; \
if test -f 'modules.mk'; then \
    if test -n 'mod_ssl.la'; then \
        echo "Building shared: mod_ssl.la"; \
        if test "$made_local" != "yes"; then \
                make "local-shared-build" || exit 1; \
        fi; \
    fi; \
fi; \
if test `pwd` = "/vikram/apache_2_0_65/httpd-2.0.65"; then \
        echo "" ; \
fi
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `shared-build-recursive'
Current working directory /vikram/apache_2_0_65/httpd-2.0.65/modules/ssl
*** Error code 1
The following command caused the error:
if test `pwd` = "/vikram/apache_2_0_65/httpd-2.0.65"; then \
    echo "" ; \
fi; \
list='aaa cache experimental filters loggers metadata proxy ssl http dav/main generators dav/fs mappers'; for i in $list; do \
    target="shared-build"; \
    if test "$i" = "."; then \
        made_local=yes; \
        target="local-shared-build"; \
    fi; \
    if test "$i" != "srclib"; then \
        (cd $i && make $target) || exit 1; \
    fi; \
done; \
if test -f 'modules.mk'; then \
    if test -n ''; then \
        echo "Building shared: "; \
        if test "$made_local" != "yes"; then \
                make "local-shared-build" || exit 1; \
        fi; \
    fi; \
fi; \
if test `pwd` = "/vikram/apache_2_0_65/httpd-2.0.65"; then \
        echo "" ; \
fi
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `shared-build-recursive'
Current working directory /vikram/apache_2_0_65/httpd-2.0.65/modules
*** Error code 1
The following command caused the error:
if test `pwd` = "/vikram/apache_2_0_65/httpd-2.0.65"; then \
    echo "" ; \
fi; \
list='srclib os server modules support'; for i in $list; do \
    target="shared-build"; \
    if test "$i" = "."; then \
        made_local=yes; \
        target="local-shared-build"; \
    fi; \
    if test "$i" != "srclib"; then \
        (cd $i && make $target) || exit 1; \
    fi; \
done; \
if test -f 'modules.mk'; then \
    if test -n ''; then \
        echo "Building shared: "; \
        if test "$made_local" != "yes"; then \
                make "local-shared-build" || exit 1; \
        fi; \
    fi; \
fi; \
if test `pwd` = "/vikram/apache_2_0_65/httpd-2.0.65"; then \
        echo "" ; \
fi
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `shared-build-recursive'
Current working directory /vikram/apache_2_0_65/httpd-2.0.65
*** Error code 1
The following command caused the error:
otarget=`echo all-recursive|sed s/-recursive//`; \
list='  srclib os server modules support'; \
for i in $list; do \
    if test -d "$i"; then \
        target="$otarget"; \
        echo "Making $target in $i"; \
        if test "$i" = "."; then \
                made_local=yes; \
                target="local-$target"; \
        fi; \
        (cd $i && make $target) || exit 1; \
    fi; \
done; \
if test "$otarget" = "all" && test -z 'httpd shared-build suexec'; then \
    made_local=yes; \
fi; \
if test "$made_local" != "yes"; then \
    make "local-$otarget" || exit 1; \
fi
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `all-recursive'
```

Can anyone help me? How can i overcome this error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to recompile your openssl in shared mode, in order the libraries would be shared for compile apache.

./Configure your_architecture shared
or
./config shared